# Generate dynamic Modals using Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to generate dynamic modals using Ionic, and have created a controller that dynamically has the id of the ng-repeat item which is linked to a unique modal. The modal is under a   under the ion-item

**Controller**

```
$scope.showModal = function(id){

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(id+'-modal.html', {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
          }).then(function(modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
          });       

    window.modal.show();

    $scope.openModal = function() {
        $scope.modal.show();
      };
      $scope.closeModal = function() {
        $scope.modal.hide();
      };        
}
```

View

```
 < ion-item collection-repeat="hist in history" ng-show="history.length" style="background:none;border:none">

<div class="list card"   ng-click="showModal(id)">

                    <div class="item ">
                        <div class="row" >
                          <div class="col col-25" > <span style="float:left;padding-top:0.4em"><i class="ion-clock largericon"></i></span>  </div>

                          <div class="col col-75" align="left"> 
                            <div style="float:left">
                                <div style="font-size:2em">{{hist.session_time}} </div> 
                                <div style="color:#999">  {{hist.human_date}}</div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div> 
                    </div>
</div>

      <script id="1-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-modal-view style="background:#24112B"> 
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-royal">
          <h1 class="title">Session Started... </h1>
          <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()"><i class="ion-close-round"></i></button>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="padding">

        <div style="padding-top:1.3em;padding-bottom:1.3em">
            <div class="row" align="center" >
              <div class="col col-100" align="center">Start by keeping your repetitions to the beat...</div>
            </div> 


        </div>

        </ion-content>
      </ion-modal-view>
     </script>  
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

See it working: https://plnkr.co/edit/UcoU4i?p=preview

```
$scope.showModal = function(id){
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(id+'-modal.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
      $scope.modal.show(); // show modal after it was loaded
    });        
}
```

EDIT: Also make sure `ng-click="showModal(id)"` you pass some actual `id`...

Comment: I am trying to do the above, but keep getting GET file:///android_asset/www/undefined.html net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. For the modal script tag I use: id="{{hist.id}}-modal.html". When I look in the html source the numbers are correct inside both the script id tag and also in the showModal(1) parameter. So not sure why this would happen... any idea?

Comment: ```android_asset``` suggests that you run some wrapper / Cordova thingy... Have you tried regular modals - are they retrieved? In my example I put ```html template``` directly under ```ng-app```, that also might be a difference.